# Expressjs regex match route with extensions

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm using expressjs and I want to be able to match a route for only two specific cases.

`/item/list.xml` or `/item/list.json`

I've tried to use `'/:item/:list(list.xml|list.json)`, but this doesn't work.  Any ideas how to match this?

Thanks!

Comment: :list will be the second param, cant you then split it by the "." (dot) ?

Comment: Yeah, would just be nice to ignore the route entirely.

Comment: What do you mean?